# grap a URL from a column and paste in chrome

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I have an Excel file with a column filled with +4000 URLs each one in a different cell. I need to use Python to open it with Chrome and scraping the website some of the data from a website.
past them in excel.

And then do the same step for the next URL. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: One option is to check out the `requests` (or perhaps `requests_html`) library to access the webpages. Then you can use the `BeautifulSoup` library to parse the DOM or what have you. You may need to make extra considerations for if you're trying to access content that needs rendered, though.

Answer (score 1):

export the excel file to csv file read data from it as

```py
def data_collector(url):
    # do your code here and return data that you want to write in place of url
    return url
with open("myfile.csv") as fobj:
    content = fobj.read()
    #below line will return you urls in form of list
    urls = content.replace(",", " ").strip()

for url in urls:
    data_to_be_write = data_collector(url)
    # added extra quotes to prevent csv from breaking it is prescribed
    # to use csv module to write in csv file but for ease of understanding
    # i did it like this, Hoping You will correct it by yourself
    content = "\"" + {content.replace(url, data_to_be_write) + "\""

with open("new_file.csv", "wt") as fnew:
    fnew.write(content)
```

after running this code you will get `new_file.csv` opening it with Excel you will get your desired data in place of url

if you want your url with data just append it like with data in string seprated by colon.